# cURL SSL Request Failure

Tags: php, xml, rest, curl, ssl

I am trying to send an XML feed as a string to a REST service that is hosted on an SSL server. I have literally been pulling my hair out over this on and off the past few months for a client and they have said it works within their system and externally so it must be either our server or our script as far as they're concerned.

This is the PHP script.

```
<?php

    $endURI     = 'https://****.****.com/Service.svc/CreateProject';

    function curlRequest($uri, $data = false)
    {
        $ch = curl_init();

        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $uri);

        if($data)
        {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);   
        }

        $response = curl_exec($ch);

        if($response)
        {
            echo $response;
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'Error Code (' . curl_errno($ch) . '): ' . curl_error($ch);
            echo '<pre>';
            var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));
            echo '</pre>';
        }

        curl_close($ch);
    }

    if($_POST['data'])
    {
        curlRequest($endURI, simplexml_load_string($_POST['data']));
    }

?>
```

The error being returned isn't very helpful but I am convinced it is something on their end due to the context of the error.

```
The server encountered an error processing the request. See server logs for more details.
```

I'll list the XML file too in case it's any help but I doubt it. It's just test data so not sensitive at all.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CreateProjectRequest>
  <RequestHeader>
    <VendorKey>****</VendorKey>
    <Password>****</Password>
    <CorrelationID>****</CorrelationID>
    <QoS>QoS1</QoS>
  </RequestHeader>
  <RequestBody>
    <Project ClientID="ClientID1" SourceID="SourceID1">
      <ProjectName>ProjectName1</ProjectName>
      <BusinessUnit>HPE (BE)</BusinessUnit>
      <LegalEntity>LegalEntity1</LegalEntity>
      <ProjectStart>1900-01-01</ProjectStart>
      <ProjectEnd>1900-01-01</ProjectEnd>
      <ProjectStatus>Active</ProjectStatus>
      <ExpectedPaymentDatePeriod>Jan-Mar</ExpectedPaymentDatePeriod>
      <ExpectedPaymentDateYear>2012</ExpectedPaymentDateYear>
      <PaymentCurrency>EUR - Euro Member Countries</PaymentCurrency>
      <SupportingSupplements>Yes</SupportingSupplements>
      <Revisions>Yes</Revisions>
      <ForeignLanguageTranslations>Yes</ForeignLanguageTranslations>
      <NumberOfEditions>This and Subsequent Editions</NumberOfEditions>
      <PromotionalUse>Right to Display in context Project/Title - All Media</PromotionalUse>
      <Derivatives>Yes</Derivatives>
      <DerivativeSubcategory>Abridgements</DerivativeSubcategory>
      <DerivativeSubcategory>Adaptations</DerivativeSubcategory>
      <DerivativeSubcategory>Brief Editions</DerivativeSubcategory>
      <AllMedia>Yes</AllMedia>
      <Print>Yes</Print>
      <Digital>Yes</Digital>
      <WorldRights>Yes</WorldRights>
      <WorldRightsExcludingNAmerica>Yes</WorldRightsExcludingNAmerica>
      <NonWorldRights>Yes</NonWorldRights>
      <TerritoriesOthers>TerritoriesOthers1</TerritoriesOthers>
      <LanguageAll>Yes</LanguageAll>
      <LanguageOthers>LanguageOthers1</LanguageOthers>
      <TitleList>
        <Title ClientID="ClientID1" SourceID="SourceID1">
          <Title>Title1</Title>
          <SeriesTitle>SeriesTitle1</SeriesTitle>
          <Authors>Authors1</Authors>
          <PubDate>1900-01-01</PubDate>
          <EditionNo>EditionNo1</EditionNo>
          <ContentType>Audio</ContentType>
          <IdentifierType>ISBN 13</IdentifierType>
          <Identifier>Identifier1</Identifier>
        </Title>
        <Title ClientID="ClientID2" SourceID="SourceID2">
          <Title>Title2</Title>
          <SeriesTitle>SeriesTitle2</SeriesTitle>
          <Authors>Authors2</Authors>
          <PubDate>0001-01-01</PubDate>
          <EditionNo>EditionNo2</EditionNo>
          <ContentType>Book</ContentType>
          <IdentifierType>Product Code</IdentifierType>
          <Identifier>Identifier2</Identifier>
        </Title>
        <Title ClientID="ClientID3" SourceID="SourceID3">
          <Title>Title3</Title>
          <SeriesTitle>SeriesTitle3</SeriesTitle>
          <Authors>Authors3</Authors>
          <PubDate>9999-12-31</PubDate>
          <EditionNo>EditionNo3</EditionNo>
          <ContentType>CD-ROM</ContentType>
          <IdentifierType>ISBN 13</IdentifierType>
          <Identifier>Identifier3</Identifier>
        </Title>
      </TitleList>
      <AssetList>
        <Asset ClientID="ClientID1" SourceID="SourceID1">
          <ContentClass>Audio</ContentClass>
          <ContentType>Activity</ContentType>
          <CaptionDesc>CaptionDesc1</CaptionDesc>
          <SourceName>SourceName1</SourceName>
          <SourceAssetID>SourceAssetID1</SourceAssetID>
          <CreditLine>CreditLine1</CreditLine>
          <PearsonReferenceNo>PearsonReferenceNo1</PearsonReferenceNo>
          <PermissionEditor>PermissionEditor1</PermissionEditor>
          <CopyrightName>CopyrightName1</CopyrightName>
          <Placement>All</Placement>
          <CurrencyCode>EUR - Euro Member Countries</CurrencyCode>
          <Pricing>Pricing1</Pricing>
          <PreviouslyClearedbyPearson>Yes</PreviouslyClearedbyPearson>
          <PearsonProductIdentifier>PearsonProductIdentifier1</PearsonProductIdentifier>
          <SubscriptionDeal>Yes</SubscriptionDeal>
          <Ownership>Ownership1</Ownership>
          <RightsClass>Pearson Wholly Owned</RightsClass>
          <ReuseStatus>Re-use prohibited</ReuseStatus>
          <LicenseExpDate>1900-01-01</LicenseExpDate>
          <LocationRelease>Obtained</LocationRelease>
          <PerformanceRelease>Obtained</PerformanceRelease>
          <ModelRelease>Obtained</ModelRelease>
          <RightsAsRequested>Yes</RightsAsRequested>
          <FormatAsRequested>Yes</FormatAsRequested>
          <TerritoriesAsRequested>Yes</TerritoriesAsRequested>
          <LanguageAsRequested>Yes</LanguageAsRequested>
          <SupportingSupplements>Yes</SupportingSupplements>
          <Revisions>Yes</Revisions>
          <ForeignLanguageTranslations>Yes</ForeignLanguageTranslations>
          <NumberOfEditions>This and Subsequent Editions</NumberOfEditions>
          <PromotionalUse>Right to Display in context Project/Title - All Media</PromotionalUse>
          <Derivatives>Yes</Derivatives>
          <DerivativeSubcategory>Abridgements</DerivativeSubcategory>
          <DerivativeSubcategory>Adaptations</DerivativeSubcategory>
          <DerivativeSubcategory>Brief Editions</DerivativeSubcategory>
          <AllMedia>Yes</AllMedia>
          <AllMediaQuantity>AllMediaQuantity1</AllMediaQuantity>
          <Print>Yes</Print>
          <PrintQuantity>PrintQuantity1</PrintQuantity>
          <Digital>Yes</Digital>
          <DigitalQuantity>DigitalQuantity1</DigitalQuantity>
          <WorldRights>Yes</WorldRights>
          <WorldRightsExcludingNAmerica>Yes</WorldRightsExcludingNAmerica>
          <NonWorldRights>Yes</NonWorldRights>
          <OtherTerritories>OtherTerritories1</OtherTerritories>
          <AllLanguages>Yes</AllLanguages>
          <OtherLanguages>OtherLanguages1</OtherLanguages>
          <RightsRestrictions>RightsRestrictions1</RightsRestrictions>
          <GeneralComments>GeneralComments1</GeneralComments>
          <PermissionCleared>Yes</PermissionCleared>
          <TitleReferences>
            <TitleRef ClientID="ClientID1" />
            <TitleRef ClientID="ClientID2" />
            <TitleRef ClientID="ClientID3" />
          </TitleReferences>
        </Asset>
        <Asset ClientID="ClientID2" SourceID="SourceID2">
          <ContentClass>Image</ContentClass>
          <ContentType>Advertisement</ContentType>
          <CaptionDesc>CaptionDesc2</CaptionDesc>
          <SourceName>SourceName2</SourceName>
          <SourceAssetID>SourceAssetID2</SourceAssetID>
          <CreditLine>CreditLine2</CreditLine>
          <PearsonReferenceNo>PearsonReferenceNo2</PearsonReferenceNo>
          <PermissionEditor>PermissionEditor2</PermissionEditor>
          <CopyrightName>CopyrightName2</CopyrightName>
          <Placement>Cover</Placement>
          <CurrencyCode>HKD - Hong Kong Dollar</CurrencyCode>
          <Pricing>Pricing2</Pricing>
          <PreviouslyClearedbyPearson>No</PreviouslyClearedbyPearson>
          <PearsonProductIdentifier>PearsonProductIdentifier2</PearsonProductIdentifier>
          <SubscriptionDeal>No</SubscriptionDeal>
          <Ownership>Ownership2</Ownership>
          <RightsClass>Rights Manged</RightsClass>
          <ReuseStatus>Re-use permitted with clearance</ReuseStatus>
          <LicenseExpDate>0001-01-01</LicenseExpDate>
          <LocationRelease>Not Obtained</LocationRelease>
          <PerformanceRelease>Not Obtained</PerformanceRelease>
          <ModelRelease>Not Obtained</ModelRelease>
          <RightsAsRequested>No</RightsAsRequested>
          <FormatAsRequested>No</FormatAsRequested>
          <TerritoriesAsRequested>No</TerritoriesAsRequested>
          <LanguageAsRequested>No</LanguageAsRequested>
          <SupportingSupplements>No</SupportingSupplements>
          <Revisions>No</Revisions>
          <ForeignLanguageTranslations>No</ForeignLanguageTranslations>
          <NumberOfEditions>This Edition only</NumberOfEditions>
          <PromotionalUse>Right to Display in context Project/Title - Digitial</PromotionalUse>
          <Derivatives>No</Derivatives>
          <DerivativeSubcategory>Custom Versions</DerivativeSubcategory>
          <DerivativeSubcategory>Split Editions</DerivativeSubcategory>
          <DerivativeSubcategory>Versions</DerivativeSubcategory>
          <AllMedia>No</AllMedia>
          <AllMediaQuantity>AllMediaQuantity2</AllMediaQuantity>
          <Print>No</Print>
          <PrintQuantity>PrintQuantity2</PrintQuantity>
          <Digital>No</Digital>
          <DigitalQuantity>DigitalQuantity2</DigitalQuantity>
          <WorldRights>No</WorldRights>
          <WorldRightsExcludingNAmerica>No</WorldRightsExcludingNAmerica>
          <NonWorldRights>No</NonWorldRights>
          <OtherTerritories>OtherTerritories2</OtherTerritories>
          <AllLanguages>No</AllLanguages>
          <OtherLanguages>OtherLanguages2</OtherLanguages>
          <RightsRestrictions>RightsRestrictions2</RightsRestrictions>
          <GeneralComments>GeneralComments2</GeneralComments>
          <PermissionCleared>No</PermissionCleared>
          <TitleReferences>
            <TitleRef ClientID="ClientID4" />
            <TitleRef ClientID="ClientID5" />
            <TitleRef ClientID="ClientID6" />
          </TitleReferences>
        </Asset>
        <Asset ClientID="ClientID3" SourceID="SourceID3">
          <ContentClass>Text</ContentClass>
          <ContentType>Appendices</ContentType>
          <CaptionDesc>CaptionDesc3</CaptionDesc>
          <SourceName>SourceName3</SourceName>
          <SourceAssetID>SourceAssetID3</SourceAssetID>
          <CreditLine>CreditLine3</CreditLine>
          <PearsonReferenceNo>PearsonReferenceNo3</PearsonReferenceNo>
          <PermissionEditor>PermissionEditor3</PermissionEditor>
          <CopyrightName>CopyrightName3</CopyrightName>
          <Placement>Electronic</Placement>
          <CurrencyCode>ZAR - South African rand</CurrencyCode>
          <Pricing>Pricing3</Pricing>
          <PreviouslyClearedbyPearson>Yes</PreviouslyClearedbyPearson>
          <PearsonProductIdentifier>PearsonProductIdentifier3</PearsonProductIdentifier>
          <SubscriptionDeal>Yes</SubscriptionDeal>
          <Ownership>Ownership3</Ownership>
          <RightsClass>Royalty Free</RightsClass>
          <ReuseStatus>Re-use prohibited</ReuseStatus>
          <LicenseExpDate>9999-12-31</LicenseExpDate>
          <LocationRelease>Not Applicable</LocationRelease>
          <PerformanceRelease>Not Applicable</PerformanceRelease>
          <ModelRelease>Not Applicable</ModelRelease>
          <RightsAsRequested>Yes</RightsAsRequested>
          <FormatAsRequested>Yes</FormatAsRequested>
          <TerritoriesAsRequested>Yes</TerritoriesAsRequested>
          <LanguageAsRequested>Yes</LanguageAsRequested>
          <SupportingSupplements>Yes</SupportingSupplements>
          <Revisions>Yes</Revisions>
          <ForeignLanguageTranslations>Yes</ForeignLanguageTranslations>
          <NumberOfEditions>This and Subsequent Editions</NumberOfEditions>
          <PromotionalUse>Right to Display in context Project/Title - Print</PromotionalUse>
          <Derivatives>Yes</Derivatives>
          <DerivativeSubcategory>Abridgements</DerivativeSubcategory>
          <DerivativeSubcategory>Adaptations</DerivativeSubcategory>
          <DerivativeSubcategory>Brief Editions</DerivativeSubcategory>
          <AllMedia>Yes</AllMedia>
          <AllMediaQuantity>AllMediaQuantity3</AllMediaQuantity>
          <Print>Yes</Print>
          <PrintQuantity>PrintQuantity3</PrintQuantity>
          <Digital>Yes</Digital>
          <DigitalQuantity>DigitalQuantity3</DigitalQuantity>
          <WorldRights>Yes</WorldRights>
          <WorldRightsExcludingNAmerica>Yes</WorldRightsExcludingNAmerica>
          <NonWorldRights>Yes</NonWorldRights>
          <OtherTerritories>OtherTerritories3</OtherTerritories>
          <AllLanguages>Yes</AllLanguages>
          <OtherLanguages>OtherLanguages3</OtherLanguages>
          <RightsRestrictions>RightsRestrictions3</RightsRestrictions>
          <GeneralComments>GeneralComments3</GeneralComments>
          <PermissionCleared>Yes</PermissionCleared>
          <TitleReferences>
            <TitleRef ClientID="ClientID7" />
            <TitleRef ClientID="ClientID8" />
            <TitleRef ClientID="ClientID9" />
          </TitleReferences>
        </Asset>
      </AssetList>
    </Project>
  </RequestBody>
</CreateProjectRequest>
```

If anyone can solve this I would be so appreciative!

Comment: Have you tried to attack this problem other way around, i.e. _with_ SSL verification? I mean using CURLOPT_CAINFO with authority bundle.

Comment: It might be an option. Will have to speak to my employer tomorrow to see if he can get hold of one. I would like to be a last resort, however.

Comment: Actually, CA bundle can be freely downloaded it's just a bundle of Certification Authorities (CA) certificates from trusted organizations who can sign and distribute SSL certificates (e.g. VeriSign). During web browsing, a browser is doing such a check (with such CA certificates already built-in), in your case you need to download the CA bundle for this check. If you can call their service via browser you can check what CA certificates are required for the bundle.

Answer (score 0):

This is most definitely an error generated on their end. If it was a curl error, based on your code, the error would be prepended with this: echo 'Error Code (' . curl_errno($ch) . '): ' . curl_error($ch);

You may, however, be sending a bad request? I'd set up a catch for this phrase and log both the raw outgoing and incoming xml to a log file / db to bring the their attention.

Comment: I thought this may be the case but they have assured us that the request is correct and it should be working. They also have other clients using the service and it works fine for them. I think there is an error in communication with us and them. How would I go about monitoring and logging outgoing and incoming communication?

Comment: The problem with what they are saying is that you have no code to produce an error. After googling for that statement, I see that it is an error produced either by a .NET application, or from IIS. (http://salvoz.com/blog/2011/02/18/where-are-the-server-logs/). I'm assuming since you are writing in PHP, your shop isn't using either.

I would do a check for a valid XML return payload. On Failure of parsing the xml, write your $data, $response and $error (define this: $error = curl_error($ch)) to a flat text file on your server with the date/time.